# django - Custom redirect after login

Tags: python, django, http

In my app I try to redirect after submitting a form, but it seems to does not work. 
Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from po_contest_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.graduate_signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^signup/success/$', views.signup_success, name='signup_success')

]
```

and views.py. The actual problem is in `graduate_signup` view. After receiving POST request I want to create a User and then save additional info about it. For that purpose I use User Profile approach as described [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html):

```
def graduate_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = GraduateSignUpForm(request.POST)
        print('POST has been received')

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.graduate.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.save()
            print('user is signed up')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            print('user is signed in')
            return redirect('signup_success')
        else:
            print('form has some errors')
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = GraduateSignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'graduate_signup.html', {'form': form})


def signup_success(request):
    return render(request, 'signup_finished.html')
```

After submitting form in browser, I can see logs in Django console:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 19, 2018 - 08:05:32
Django version 1.11.7, using settings 'po_contest.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[19/Jan/2018 08:05:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 922
[19/Jan/2018 08:05:36] "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6484
POST has been received
user is signed up
user is signed in
[19/Jan/2018 08:05:56] "POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jan/2018 08:05:56] "GET /signup/success/ HTTP/1.1" 200 758
```

However in browser I still see my signup page with the form, and no page I'm trying redirect to.

My question: what can cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to achieve this is to provide [LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#login-url) and [LOGIN_URL_REDIRECT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) in `settings.py` file of your project. And then provide some logic in confirmation, something like:

```
def confirmation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfirmationForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_login = False
            user.save()
            return redirect('some_page')
    else:
        if not user.first_login:
            login(request, request.user)
            return redirect('some_page')

        form = ConfirmationForm(instance=request.user)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'confirmation.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if I want to redirect to page with signup confirmation message only once, after signup? I login user here only because it's good for user experience IMHO.

Comment: Why you need to redirect to login page after signup? To use it properly you need to wrap all needed views with `login_required` decorator, then user will be redirected to login page if he is not sign up yet. If he is already signed up then no login required

Comment: I want to redirect to signup confirmation page after signup, not login page.

Comment: Then you need to have some boolean value on user which will indicate that user and then provide some logic in confirmation.

Comment: Update the answer with example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return redirect change it to HTTPResponseRedirect

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse

def graduate_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = GraduateSignUpForm(request.POST)
        print('POST has been received')

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.graduate.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.save()
            print('user is signed up')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            print('user is signed in')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/signup/success/')
        else:
            print('form has some errors')
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = GraduateSignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'graduate_signup.html', {'form': form})


def signup_success(request):
    return render(request, 'signup_finished.html')
```